Flutter Keyboard Flicker when moving from Email Textformfield to password Textformfield
When I move from Email to password, the keyboard suggestion box flicker. I think it has to do with the focus node but I could not fix it despite trying solutions that I'd found on here!
SizedBox(
  width: 325,
  child: TextFormField(
    autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.email],
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      label: Text(
        'email'.tr,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
      ),
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.email,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 0.5),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    ),
    onChanged: (v) => setState(() {
      email = v;
    }),
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  ),
),
SizedBox(height: 10),
SizedBox(
  width: 325,
  child: TextFormField(
    autofillHints: const <String>[
      AutofillHints.newPassword
    ],
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      label: Text(
        'password'.tr,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
      ),
      prefixIcon:
          Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.orange),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 0.5),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    ),
    onChanged: (v) => setState(() {
      pw = v;
    }),
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    obscureText: true,
    onFieldSubmitted: (v) async {
      await auth(ref, context, email, pw);
    },
  ),
),


The issue is probably with the Autofill try it without using the AutofillHints.
Check this - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88354

it did not fix. I can see that the suggested box disappear and appear again this is prob why there is a flicker.
